# Installing Wildfly 10.0.0 on ubuntu 16.0 could not be able to configure init.d file

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, wildfly-10

I am using the command sudo cp /opt/wildfly/bin/init.d/wildfly.conf /etc/default/wildfly to copy and edit the init.d file. I am getting this error
cp: cannot stat '/opt/wildfly/bin/init.d/wildfly.conf': No such file or directory> When I check in my bin, I cannot see the init.d file. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **wildfly 10** `init.d` file located in `${WILDFLY_HOME}/docs/contrib/scripts/` directory

So you need to run

```
cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh /etc/init.d/wildfly
```

and

Debian:

```
cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/init.d/wildfly.conf /etc/default/wildfly
```

RedHat:

```
cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/init.d/wildfly.conf /etc/default/wildfly.conf
```